# property in route undefined in controller

Tags: ember.js

In the IndexRoute of my Ember hello world app, I start a `setInterval` function that I wish to allow the end user to turn off (with `clearInterval`) by clicking a dom element in the template, which triggers an action in the IndexController. So, the `setIntervalId` is set in the IndexRoute, and I need to pass it to `clearInterval` in the IndexController, but the way I have it below, the `setIntervalId` is `undefined`.  I also tried to use `App.IndexRoute.setIntervalId` to no avail. 
How would I accomplish this?

```
(function() {
  window.App = Ember.Application.create({

   LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
   LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true 
    });



  App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

      setIntervalId: 0, 

      model: function() {
         this.setIntervalId = setInterval(this.someInterval, 5000)
      },
      someInterval: function(){
        var datasource = 'http://hackernews/blahblah';
        return new Ember.$.ajax({url: datasource, dataType: "json", type: 'GET'}).then(function(data){  
             return data; 
        })
      },


});

 App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     actions: {
          clearTimeout: function(){
            console.log('clearing interval', this.setIntervalId); //undefined
            clearInterval(this.setIntervalId);

         }
         }
    })
})();
```

template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">>
    <h1>Hi Babe</hi>
        {{ outlet }}
    <label {{action "clearTimeout" on="click"}}>clear timeout</label>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the model, you need to return the value in the route’s `model` function:

```
model: function() {
  return this.setIntervalId = setInterval(this.someInterval, 5000)
}
```

To access the model in the controller, you need to use `this.get('model')`.

```
actions: {
  clearTimeout: function(){
     console.log('clearing interval', this.get('model');
     clearInterval(this.get('model'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so whatever's returned from the model function `is` the model?

Comment: Yes, that’s the [purpose of the `model` function](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).